# android load local(in Asset/Res/External Storage) pdf file in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

```
I want to display pdf file in webview.
I try using this code it displays blank page.
File retrieve perfacly but not display in webView.
Put screen shoot of webview displays webview when i run the application.
display blank webview. like this....
```

[image]

```
private WebView view;
Uri path;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents/MyPDFFILE.pdf");
        path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        view.setContentDescription("application/pdf");
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(path.toString());

        // view.loadUrl("http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter10-WebKit.pdf");
    }
```

Comment: in commented code i load internet pdf which also be not load in webview. but when i use google pdf viewer link  "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter10-WebKit.pdf" then its open in default browser but not in webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, Android `WebView` doesn't support **PDF** file functionality. And `WebView` cannot render PDFs.

The URL you posted on your comments it displayed pdf file in native web browser because of it **uses Google Docs**.

If you want to display pdf file in your webview then using Google Docs pass url of your pdf file which located on server not in your local.

**Update:**
Code for display pdf file located on net in webview.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: But the question was for how to do this for a local PDF file, does this solution work in that case too?